# Scala Predicates, and Filter functions?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a very simple example of a set s1 {1, 2} and I want to apply a predicate p > 1 on it. Now I have implemented this function, and it is giving me correct results.

```
  def filter(s: Set, p: Int => Boolean): Set = {(i: Int) => s(i) && p(i)}
```

Where definition of set is

```
  type Set = Int => Boolean
```

But is there a more elegant way of doing it in Scala?

Comment: I guess you have a good reason to define `Set` like this and not use standard Scala collection library?

Comment: Yes, it is part of Martin Odersky's Coursera course assignment.

Comment: @user1343318 You can drop the `{}` and the type annotation after `i`, so the body would look like this: `i => s(i) && p(i)`. Other than that it looks fine... :)

Comment: Scala doesn't have built-in predicates support (i.e. boolean logic), but it's easy enough to write your own combinators (http://timepit.eu/~frank/blog/2012/08/combining_predicates_in_scala/) or import a library (https://github.com/wheaties/Predicates) if necessary. For your purposes your answer is fine.

Comment: Can you be more precise with the question. Why do you think this is not elegant? You can leave away the type annotation for `i` by the way, because it is inferred. `def filter(s: Set)(p: Int => Boolean): Set = { i => s(i) && p(i) }`

Comment: @LuigiPlinge I guess predicates is just meant as functions returning a boolean value

Answer (score 5):

Using this course's definition of what a `Set` is, your answer is very elegant.

Since the predicate is in fact a `Set` too, `filter` could have been much more terse by reusing the `intersect` function:

```scala
/**
 * Returns the intersection of the two given sets,
 * the set of all elements that are both in `s` and `t`.
 */
def intersect(s: Set, t: Set): Set = ???

/**
 * Returns the subset of `s` for which `p` holds.
 */
def filter(s: Set, p: Int => Boolean): Set = intersect(s, p)
```

I left the intersect implementation out because the [Coursera Honor Code](https://www.coursera.org/about/honorcode) prevents sharing assignment answers.